# Laravel elixir auto concatenating coffee files

Tags: laravel, coffeescript, gulp

I have just installed again laravel 5 via composer. Then proceeded to follow instructions on installation and setup of laravel elixir.

The thing is, elixir is auto concatenating my coffee files.  Here is the contents of my gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.coffee().less('app.less');
});
```

I have the following sample files in these locations:

```
resources/assets/coffee/sample/myApp.coffee
resources/assets/coffee/sample/controllers/sampleController.coffee
resources/assets/coffee/sample/directives/sampleDirective.coffee
```

After running gulp, the output is in:

```
public/js/app.js
```

The 3 coffee files are concatenated within the output file.

If I try this on a older install of laravel 5, about a month old, it works as expected. The files are not concatenated and the directory structure is intact.

I have taken a peek at the:
    node_modules/laravel-elixir/package.json

On the new installation, elixir version is 2.1.1 while on the old one is 1.0.3.

Anyone can shed a light on this?

Comment: I have temporarily edited the package.json and changed the laravel-elixir version from "*" to "1.0.3" so that I can continue to work while awaiting feedback from this.

Comment: Confirmed, the default behavior for `.coffee()` has changed dramatically.

I thought you might be able to use an `elixer.json` file to override some of the configs, but I can't seem to get that right...

Comment: see https://github.com/laravel/elixir/commit/9f1dca07170870cb8b755b9a1c1825625f1d5d9b